# issue vector layer and marker not plot on both side of dateline at same time

Tags: openlayers, gis

Please Help Me vector layer and markers not plot both side of dateline at same time .please check below issue occur same.
 For Vector layer
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20981/openlayers-vector-layer-polygons-not-displaying-properly-with-osm

**for marker**
i am using openlayer 2 and i am using kml for world map and i show markers with animation cluster

http://acuriousanimal.com/code/animatedCluster/

marker plot same as
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJR9B.gif

Comment: your question isn't very clear. Could you post your code?

Comment: Problem http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20981/openlayers-vector-layer-polygons-not-displaying-properly-with-osm  http://acuriousanimal.com/code/animatedCluster/

marker plot same as http://i.stack.imgur.com/GJR9B.gif